# Handling Permission PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel-4, permissions

Need suggestion for handling user permission, My application has 2 factors :

1. Location
2. Modules

**Scenario:**

A user in system might have access to 3 modules in **location1** and 2 modules in **location2**

Now how should i handle my Table

**Method 1:**

Assigning a permission column in the user table it self and separating permission using delimiter example:

Permission(column) : loc1m1,loc1m2,loc1m3,loc2m1,loc2m2

**Method 2:**

having a separate table for the permissions:

```
| id | userid | location | module | status |
|----|--------|----------|--------|--------|
| 1  | 1      | loc1     | 1      | 1      |
| 2  | 1      | loc1     | 2      | 1      |
| 3  | 1      | loc1     | 3      | 1      |
| 4  | 1      | loc2     | 1      | 1      |
| 5  | 1      | loc2     | 2      | 1      |
```

Or If there is a better practice i would like to know about it

each person will have different permission so defining roles is not required.

Kindly share your insights. here is the schema

http://www.laravelsd.com/share/7fOnku

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do not do Method 1.

Method 2 is generally the accepted way of doing it. This way you can run queries about who has access to specific areas, or what areas a certain user can access.

The other option is to use a package that handles access control for you - I generally use https://github.com/BeatSwitch/lock-laravel

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have looked into [Access Control List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) yet but laravel and symfony both have really good articles on the matter and some amazing bundles that work well so you might be kinda inventing the wheel.

take a look at these articles:

https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-acl-a7f2fa1f9791

http://ollieread.com/blog/2014/03/18/a-simplified-laravel-acl/

packages:

https://packagist.org/packages/jacopo/laravel-authentication-acl

https://github.com/intrip/laravel-authentication-acl

Comment: I need to set permission individually for each person and not create roles !! and most of the package forces us to create roles

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create 5 table:

main table

1. Users(id, name, ...)
2. Locations(id, name, ...)
3. Moduls(id, name, ...)

pivot table:

4. users_locations(id, users_id, locations_id)
5. locations_moduls(id, locations_id, moduls_id)

After this you can use table joins (many-to-many). If you use laravel, this can help you: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel